# Is an iAP receipt restored from an iCloud backup?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud

If a user has made a purchase from an app on a device and then that device is backed up to iCloud and then restored from iCloud (either to the same device or to a different device) then if the receipt is attempted to be retried via

let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL 
if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url)
 ...

Then if there was a receive when the app was backed to iCloud, will it be present when restored?

Its not possible to try this out and test it because the Sandbox IAP app id cannot be used for the iCloud backup/restore.

I have observed that not everything relating to either the device or an app gets restored from iCloud (when restoring to a different device) hence I cannot assume the receipt will be just because most things are, hence this question.

Has anybody with experience of an iAP app in the app store and iCloud backup/restore, in particular to a different device, able to confirm if the receipt is or isn't restored also?